# Stuck at "Started bpfilter"

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I use Kubuntu 18.04, and yesterday I tried to install Nvidia drivers (I use iGPU and GTX 1060), so I followed these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I didn't reboot, and today when I start my PC I see after boot "Started bpfilter" and nothing happens, I am stuck, I can go to another TTY, so I tried to uninstall nvidia drivers using:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Rebooted and didn't help, I tried even reinstall xorg and sddm.

This is output from `sudo lshw -c video`:

[image: lshw]

I want to use iGPU for my primary display.